# Iterate through ordered collection, begin at arbitrary position and do a full circle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iteration, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a collection of 10 objects, each with a unique position attribute 1-10.

If I would iterate the collection beginning from position 1, I would simply do:

```
collection.order(position: :asc).each
```

But how would I cycle through the collection but begin on another position, say position 5 (and consequently end on position 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

> collection.order(position: :asc).rotate(5).each

[Docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/rotate)